# validating minlength and maxlength in md-text-float

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I want to validate if the user is entering an input between 4-20 characters of length into a md-text-float (angular material directive), with plain angular I would just insert the ng-minlength and ng-maxlength attributes into an  tag then validate. But in  it doesn't work. How should I validate if the text float holds the required string length and enable the submit button?

```
<md-text-float label="password" data-ng-model="formPassword" 
                               data-ng-minlength="4" data-ng-maxlength="20" type="password" data-ng-required="true"></md-text-float>
```

and then enabling.

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" data-ng-click="submitLogin()" data-ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid">login</md-button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually For md-text-float directive ng-minlenght and all will not work, validations are still in progress,You can see the link also

https://github.com/angular/material/issues/372

Still, if you want to validate then try to validate it in controller itself to handle validation.

Comment: actaully, seeing this post https://github.com/angular/material/issues/872 ,I found I can actually implement the ng-minlength and ng-maxlength features by omitting the ng prefix, I've tested it and it works but it feels a bit hackish so I'll just wait until proper support comes.

Comment: Yes.You are right and thanks for the link.But i think without ng if you are using it then it is validate it by html5.So, before angular starts it validation browser will start to validate the field.It may lead to conflict i guess.

Comment: Nice, I didn't knew that, I'll accept your answer and edit it once proper validation will be available.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate material design inputs, I would suggest using md-input-group directly rather than md-text-float (which uses md-input-group internally), until it supports validation out-of-the-box. I couldn't do a plunker for you, as the site is down - will try to do later on, once the site is back up.

But to give you an idea, the html will look something like this:-

```
<div class="field" layout="column" layout-align="center center">
     <md-input-group>
           <label for="email">Email</label>
           <md-input type="email" id="email" name="email" required maxlength="50" 
                ng-model="loginVm.user.email"></md-input>
     </md-input-group>
     <span class="error-message email-error" ng-if="loginform.$submitted && loginform.email.$invalid">Please enter a valid email address.</span>
</div>
```